# How to get only one row from a table using cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to retrieve data from one of the rows of a table using cakephp, and I want to get the values from the extracted row.

P.s. I've tried to follow cakephp's find(), but did not get anything, got an error instead.
        [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stPEb.jpg)`$login_id = $this->AppAuth->user('id');
        $userSettings= $this->loadModel("UserSettings");

```
    $userSetting= $this->$userSettings->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('UserSettings.user_id' => $login_id)));`
```

Comment: This is not cake 3.x

Answer (score 0):

[From cakephp site](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html)Got it.

`$query = $internSettings->find('all', [
      'conditions' => ['InternSettings.intern_id' => $login_id]
            ]);
  $row = $query->first();`

Now that I can retrieve a row, how am I suppose to access the values of the row?

Comment: Do the tutorials and read the manual from the beginning: book.cakephp.org you struggle with the basics that are explained in the tutorials and in the book if you would just read the according chapters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$record = $internSettings->find('all', [ 'conditions' => ['InternSettings.intern_id' => $login_id]])->first();
```

This will returns Entity object in `$record`, you can access field by

```
echo $record->field_name;
```

or you can convert it in array and then you can access

```
$recordArr=$record->toArray();
echo $recordArr['field_name'];
```